# RecyclerView that implements OnItemTouchListener with LinearLayoutManager scrolling normally

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I am trying to implement a use-case where I need to scroll RecyclerView normally (Android LayoutManager scroll) when the user scrolls with a low velocity and scroll by a certain extra amount when the user scrolls above a certain velocity.

I have implemented a LinearLayoutManager as follows:

```
public class ScrollLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    // constructors

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttachedToWindow");
        super.onAttachedToWindow(recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new ThresholdDetector());
    }

    private final class ThresholdDetector implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent e) {
            // some calculations
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(final RecyclerView view, final MotionEvent e) {
            final int action = e.getActionMasked();
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(e);
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (thresholdMet) {
                    // Custom scroll
                    mRecyclerView.scrollBy(calculatedAmount)
                } else {
                    // Scroll normally as per Android LinearLayoutManager
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If threshold is not met, I need Android to handle the scroll, otherwise I am not able to smooth scroll. I tried the following in else (when threshold is not met), but it does not quite work.

```
                    mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollBy(-(int)getDeltaX(motionEvent), 0);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the entirety of the `ThresholdDetector` class, it will be impossible to know for sure what the best solution is. That said, I believe the problem is that you are always returning `true` from `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

In the documentation for the return value of `onInterceptTouchEvent()`:

> Returns: `true` if this `OnItemTouchListener` wishes to begin intercepting touch events, `false` to continue with the current behavior and continue observing future events in the gesture.

And in the description for `onTouchEvent()`:

> Process a touch event as part of a gesture that was claimed by returning `true` from a previous call to `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

In other words, `onTouchEvent()` will only be invoked whenever you return `true` for a given event from `onInterceptTouchEvent()`. If you want the RecyclerView to perform its default behavior, simply return `false` from `onInterceptTouchEvent()` when the scroll velocity is below your threshold.

Comment: I was under the wrong impression that if you return true once from onInterceptTouchEvent() then all subsequent gestures and events will be directed to onTouchEvent. But returning true only restricts for that particular gesture.